# Does dispatchEvent trigger `default` handler?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I created this short snippet to test whether it's possible to trigger `default` handler in JavaScript event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script></script>
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e){
    console.log('mousedown', e);
    if (e.target === document.getElementById('target')) {
        if (!e.__redispatched) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var ne = new MouseEvent('mousedown', e);
            ne.__redispatched = true;
            setTimeout(function (){
                e.target.focus();
                e.target.dispatchEvent(ne);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}, true);
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="target"/>
        <input type="text"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expected that `target` input would receive event and process it as normal, thus moving caret to the correct position (like it does normally on `mousedown`). But nothing happens.

My question:
Am I doing something wrong with `dispatchEvent` or do browsers ignore default handlers when processing synthetic events? Is there any material/proof to that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately browsers do ignore default event handlers for **untrusted** events.

See [3.4 Trusted events in the W3C UI Events Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#trusted-events)

> Events that are generated by the user agent, either as a result of
>   user interaction, or as a direct result of changes to the DOM, are
>   trusted by the user agent with privileges that are not afforded to
>   events generated by script through the
>   DocumentEvent.createEvent("Event") method, modified using the
>   Event.initEvent() method, or dispatched via the
>   EventTarget.dispatchEvent() method. The isTrusted attribute of trusted
>   events has a value of true, while untrusted events have a isTrusted
>   attribute value of false.
>
> Most untrusted events should not trigger default actions, with the
>   exception of the click event. This event always triggers the default
>   action, even if the isTrusted attribute is false (this behavior is
>   retained for backward-compatibility). All other untrusted events must
>   behave as if the Event.preventDefault() method had been called on that
>   event.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the answer.

Comment: Why do they do this?